# Manjaro Linux KDE - no sound

Tags: audio, kde-plasma, pulseaudio, manjaro, pipewire

I have a problem with my Manjaro Linux. I have no sound. I have tried everything (I have installed `sof-firmware`, unmuted soundcard, rebooted alsa). What should I do?

Here is the output of the `inxi`:

`System:    Host: cWillNeverDie Kernel: 5.13.19-2-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.22.5 Distro: Manjaro Linux Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: MAG Z490 TOMAHAWK (MS-7C80) v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1.80 date: 04/19/2021 Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.19-2-MANJARO running: yes Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.38 running: yes`

Answer (score 1):

Try to open terminal and run `aplay -l`. You'll get something like:

```
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
```

Take notes each of card numbers and device numbers. For above example: card number 1 and device number 0.

Then run `speaker-test -D hw:CardNumb,DeviceNumb -c 2`. For above example become:

```
speaker -D hw:1,0 -c 2
```

If you get an error mentioning `device busy`, close all current active windows, wait a moment and run again. Do this for all cards and devices shown from `aplay -l`.

Take note which card and device that give you a sound.

After that, find on how to create `.asoundrc` on the internet.

Hope this give a clue how to debug your sound card.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this reply is too late. I was having the same problem, tried every input I could find, and nothing worked. Until...

Go to:

- audio system settings
- playback devices
- change to: analog stereo duplex

That fixed it for me, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue whenever my laptop comes out of sleep mode.

The following workaround works for me:

- unplug Headset (if there is any)
- switch sound output to another Device (e.g. from monitor to internal speaker)

Then everything works again for me

For proper analysis of the problem have a look into the answer by oprizal